# Рандомное число 0 - 1 :: с++

Tags: c++

Нигде не нашел подходящей инфы. Нужно рандомное число 0 или 1 в формате int на языке с++ используя минимум кода.

Comment: ```gettickcount() / 2```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков во-первых, оно не случайно. Во-вторых, если гугл мне не врёт, оно из winapi

Comment: @andreymal Не врет, из винапи, оно не случайно, но в среде запущенных программ в многопотоке предсказать результат серии повторов значений будет сложно :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков если тот же гугл мне не врёт, оно возвращает миллисекунды, а миллисекунда - это по компьютерным меркам целая вечность. Измерять миллисекундные интервалы не проблема даже через лагучий интернет, а значит высока вероятность, что для потенциального злоумышленника не будет проблемой удачно угадать значение (хотя для 0/1 вероятность и так 50%, но знание о миллисекунде позволит ещё больше улучшить угадывание)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков кроме того, автор не пояснил, зачем ему это - если он планирует генерировать случайное число в цикле тысячи раз, то все эти тысячи раз могут успеть выполниться за миллисекунду (современные компьютеры *быстрые*) - а значит ваш вариант тысячи раз вернёт одно и то же число

Comment: А чего так мелочиться? Генерируйте число от 0 до 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

должно решить вашу проблему

```
#include<ctime>
#include<random>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    srand(time(NULL));
    num = rand() % 2;
    cout << num;
}
```